# Automatically move hostnames to OU through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

I have a script for automating move hostnames to OU through PowerShell. But as per my script it is not working. I have tried as much as I can but it is not happening.. Can anybody help me to modify my script as per below request.

```
    # will match a d,l,D or L character before the digit
[regex]$regex = "[dlDL](?=\d)"


Get-Content -Path C:\Users\ssgrp0312\Music\uptime\move.txt | ForEach-Object {
      # check if the hostname matches the regex
    $match = $regex.Match($_)
# If MASU
    if { (  $_.Substring(0,4) = masu )
     If($match.Success){
                 if  (  $_.Substring(4,3) = thn )
             If($match.Success){
                # if client is L -> move to laptops
                    If($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "L"){
                         Write-Host "$_ is a laptop" -ForegroundColor Green
                            Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Laptops,OU=G-Corp,OU=MASU,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                     # if client is D -> move to desktops
                     }Elseif($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "D"){
                        Write-Host "$_ is a desktop" -ForegroundColor Green
                        Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=desktops,OU=G-Corp,OU=MASU,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                    }Else{
                        Write-Host "$_ not a laptop nor desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
                     }

        Elseif  (  $_.Substring(4,2) = ib )
             If($match.Success){
                # if client is L -> move to laptops
                    If($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "L"){
                         Write-Host "$_ is a laptop" -ForegroundColor Green
                            Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Laptops,OU=Indiabulls,OU=MASU,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                     # if client is D -> move to desktops
                     }Elseif($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "D"){
                        Write-Host "$_ is a desktop" -ForegroundColor Green
                        Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=desktops,OU=Indiabulls,OU=MASU,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                    }Else{
                        Write-Host "$_ not a laptop nor desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
                     }

        Elseif  (  $_.Substring(4,2) = rt )
             If($match.Success){
                # if client is L -> move to laptops
                    If($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "L"){
                         Write-Host "$_ is a laptop" -ForegroundColor Green
                            Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Laptops,OU=rtech,OU=MASU,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                     # if client is D -> move to desktops
                     }Elseif($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "D"){
                        Write-Host "$_ is a desktop" -ForegroundColor Green
                        Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=desktops,OU=rtech,OU=MASU,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                    }Else{
                        Write-Host "$_ not a laptop nor desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
                     }



        Else{  
                # if client is L -> move to laptops
                    If($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "L"){
                         Write-Host "$_ is a laptop" -ForegroundColor Green
                            Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Laptops,OU=branches,OU=MASU,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                     # if client is D -> move to desktops
                     }Elseif($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "D"){
                        Write-Host "$_ is a desktop" -ForegroundColor Green
                        Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=desktops,OU=branches,OU=MASU,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                    }Else{
                        Write-Host "$_ not a laptop nor desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
                     }}
    }

# If MAZI
    if { (  $_.Substring(0,4) = mazi )
     If($match.Success){
                 if  (  $_.Substring(4,3) = thn )
             If($match.Success){
                # if client is L -> move to laptops
                    If($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "L"){
                         Write-Host "$_ is a laptop" -ForegroundColor Green
                            Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Laptops,OU=G-Corp,OU=MAZI,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                     # if client is D -> move to desktops
                     }Elseif($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "D"){
                        Write-Host "$_ is a desktop" -ForegroundColor Green
                        Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=desktops,OU=G-Corp,OU=MAZI,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                    }Else{
                        Write-Host "$_ not a laptop nor desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
                     }

        Elseif  (  $_.Substring(4,2) = ib )
             If($match.Success){
                # if client is L -> move to laptops
                    If($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "L"){
                         Write-Host "$_ is a laptop" -ForegroundColor Green
                            Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Laptops,OU=Indiabulls,OU=MAZI,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                     # if client is D -> move to desktops
                     }Elseif($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "D"){
                        Write-Host "$_ is a desktop" -ForegroundColor Green
                        Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=desktops,OU=Indiabulls,OU=MAZI,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                    }Else{
                        Write-Host "$_ not a laptop nor desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
                     }



        Else{  
                # if client is L -> move to laptops
                    If($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "L"){
                         Write-Host "$_ is a laptop" -ForegroundColor Green
                            Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Laptops,OU=branches,OU=MAZI,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                     # if client is D -> move to desktops
                     }Elseif($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "D"){
                        Write-Host "$_ is a desktop" -ForegroundColor Green
                        Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=desktops,OU=branches,OU=MAZI,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                    }Else{
                        Write-Host "$_ not a laptop nor desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
                     }}
    }

# If MANS
    if { (  $_.Substring(0,4) = mans )
     If($match.Success){
                 if  (  $_.Substring(4,3) = thn )
             If($match.Success){
                # if client is L -> move to laptops
                    If($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "L"){
                         Write-Host "$_ is a laptop" -ForegroundColor Green
                            Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Laptops,OU=G-Corp,OU=MANS,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                     # if client is D -> move to desktops
                     }Elseif($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "D"){
                        Write-Host "$_ is a desktop" -ForegroundColor Green
                        Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=desktops,OU=G-Corp,OU=MANS,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                    }Else{
                        Write-Host "$_ not a laptop nor desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
                     }

        Elseif  (  $_.Substring(4,2) = ib )
             If($match.Success){
                # if client is L -> move to laptops
                    If($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "L"){
                         Write-Host "$_ is a laptop" -ForegroundColor Green
                            Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Laptops,OU=Indiabulls,OU=MANS,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                     # if client is D -> move to desktops
                     }Elseif($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "D"){
                        Write-Host "$_ is a desktop" -ForegroundColor Green
                        Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=desktops,OU=Indiabulls,OU=MANS,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                    }Else{
                        Write-Host "$_ not a laptop nor desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
                     }



        Else{  
                # if client is L -> move to laptops
                    If($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "L"){
                         Write-Host "$_ is a laptop" -ForegroundColor Green
                            Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Laptops,OU=branches,OU=MANS,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                     # if client is D -> move to desktops
                     }Elseif($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "D"){
                        Write-Host "$_ is a desktop" -ForegroundColor Green
                        Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=desktops,OU=branches,OU=MANS,DC=ABC,DC=COM"
                    }Else{
                        Write-Host "$_ not a laptop nor desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
                     }}
    }

Else {
 Write-Host "$_ not as per naming conversion" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Example:

> MASUDFGD001  --  ABC\MASU\BRANCHES\DESKTOPS
> MASUDFGL001  --  ABC\MASU\BRANCHES\LAPTOPS
> MASUTHNFD001 --  ABC\MASU\G-Corp\DESKTOPS
> MASUIBFGD001 --  ABC\MASU\Indiabul\DESKTOPS
>
> ```
> MAZIGHJUD003 --  ABC\MAZI\BRANCHES\DESKTOPS
> MAZIGHJUL003 --  ABC\MAZI\BRANCHES\LAPTOPS
> MAZITHNFD001 --  ABC\MAZI\G-Corp\DESKTOPS
> MAZIIBFGD001 --  ABC\MAZI\Indiabul\DESKTOPS
>
> MANSGHJUD003 --  ABC\MANSYU\BRANCHES\DESKTOPS
> MANSTHNFD001 --  ABC\MANSYU\G-Corp\DESKTOPS
> MANSTHNFL001 --  ABC\MANSYU\G-Corp\LAPTOPS
> MANSIBFGD001 --  ABC\MANSYU\Indiabul\DESKTOPS
>
> MANSGHKSK003 --  ABC\MAMBU\KISOK
> MANSTHKSK001 --  ABC\MAMBU\KISOK
> MANSIBKSK001 --  ABC\MAMBU\KISOK
> ```
>
> Rules:
>
> ```
> In Last before digits if L comes laptop
> IF D comes Desktop 
> IF KSK comes direct move to ABC\MAMBU\KISOK
>
> In first MASU comes should move to ABC\MASU\*
> If MAZI comes should move to ABC\MAZI\*
> If MANS comes ABC\MANSYU\*
> If MAHT Comes ABC\MAHTGB\*
>
> After these letters check next 3 letters
> If IB comes => Indiabul
> If THN Comes => G-corp
> Anything Else => Branches
> ```

Comment: What you're attempting is quite dangerous, make sure your `regex` is correct else you'll end up moving a bunch of computers to OUs they don't belong too. `-eq` is case insensitive by the way. A read about [`comparison_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1) can't hurt.

Comment: What machines arent being moved correctly? Are they all the same type?

Comment: @Scepticalist Everything is client OS. Win 10

Comment: I mean the NAMES - which machines are not being moved to the right OU?

Comment: Is Rules the rules you want to implement and the first block what you have so far? Because if the first block is your whole script, it's obviouse why it wouldn't work. Half of the rules are missing... You are just handling `branches`! What do you do for `Indiabul`,`G-corp` and `KISOK`?

Comment: @T-Me ..  As per my script only manages branches. I have tried for remaining as well. but it's not working. I have to do all as automate.

Comment: @Scepticalist  Only branches is moving to proper OU. Incase if it is THN it should go G-corp bu in my script wil go to branches only. Tried to edit. But it's not working.

Comment: Your script pasted above is incomplete for your requirements. Add your extra conditions and amend your script in this post if you have issues. Nobody is going to write the whole script for you.

Comment: @Masyood show us your edits that are not working. That is the part where we could help you best. Just edit your question to add the stuff that is not working.

Comment: @T-Me  I have updated my script. script is not working. Can you please help me on this

Comment: @Scepticalist  my script updated. But it is not working.